# Integrating Buycraft.net's Form/payment gateway with my bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, forms, payment-gateway

Buycraft.net have introduced a way to intergrate their webstore plugin into your website. Buycraft.net is basically a auto-donation system for Minecraft. You set up your own little webstore with them.
The idea of this is to send people straight to the payment gateway for an item they have selected,on a website, instead of having to browse the webstore.

They give me this:
I have to edit the `STORE_URL` to mine, and the `PACKAGE_ID` to mine also.

```
<form method="post" action="[STORE_URL]/checkout/pay">
<input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
<input type="text" name="ign">
<input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="paypal">
<input type="text" name="package" value="[PACKAGE_ID]">
<input type="text" name="agreement" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I got this pricing table from here : http://www.williamastrom.se/blog/twitter-bootstrap-css3-pricing-tables

I want to make the code Buycraft gave me with the 'Sign up today' button on the pricing table. (obviously I would change to either 'Buy now' or 'purchase')

Here is Williamsstroms's pricing table I got from his site as mentioned above^

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="unstyled price-table">
<li class="headline">Basic</li>
<li class="price">US $349</li>
<li class="info">Example description can be here!</li>
<li>15 Projects</li>
<li>5GB Storage</li>
<li>Unlimited Users</li>
<li>No time tracking</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#" class="button">Sign up now!</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do I make that form direct me straight to Buycraft's payment gateway?

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: Yes. That code generated text inputs, so i changed them to hidden besides the name one and edited the code to this

<form method="post" action="[acension.buycraft.net]/checkout/pay" class="form-inline">
<input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="package" value="[31534]">
<input type="hidden" name="agreement" value="true">
<input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Purchase">
</input>
</form>
Does not seem to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="http://acension.buycraft.net/checkout/pay" class="form-inline"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
 <input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="paypal"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="package" value="31534"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="agreement" value="true"> 
 <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Purchase"> </input> </form>
```

I'm not real sure why you were using brackets?  When you click it in fiddle it seems to work fine.

To be honest, I don't really have a clue what you're asking.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3ykU/

Comment: Just beat me to it, i think you've got what he's asking spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still wanting to know how to make Buycraft showup on your website here your answer
Just replace http://funkygaming.buycraft.net/   with your buycraft website url

Replace 708110    with your package ID  to get the id  just by
Clicking on Content on the top of the page,  Then go click on packages,
Then you should see a list of your packages. Now to get the ID just click in the sign that is right byside the +  Then on the top it should show something like this 
Edit package (ID: 708110)   now after ID: just copy the numbers then replace 708110  in

```
<input type="hidden" name="package" value="708110">
```

with your ID: Number. And now just past the code blow after you edit it in to the location you want this to showup at.

```
<form method="post" action="http://funkygaming.buycraft.net/checkout/pay" class="form-        inline"> 
<input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="paypal"> 
<input type="hidden" name="package" value="708110"> 
<input type="hidden" name="agreement" value="true"> 
<input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Purchase"> 
</input> 
</form>
```